# numpy.whl installation Error.(windows permission error)

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, access-denied, failed-installation

I tried to install "opencv_python-3.3.0.10-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl".. in windows 8.1, in CMD using the "pip install wheel..." command (python 3.6 pre-installed). But the following error is shown...

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages>pip install wheel 
opencv_python-3.3.0.10-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl
Collecting wheel
Using cached wheel-0.30.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Processing c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\opencv_python-3.3.0.10-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl
Collecting numpy>=1.11.3 (from opencv-python==3.3.0.10)
Downloading numpy-1.13.3-2-cp36-none-win32.whl (6.8MB)
100% |████████████████████████████████| 6.8MB 66kB/s
Installing collected packages: wheel, numpy, opencv-python
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-
packages\pip\basecommand.py"
, line 215, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
prefix=options.prefix_path,
File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 784, in install
**kwargs
File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 851, in install
self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
isolated=self.isolated,
File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 316, in clobber ensure_dir(destdir)
File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
os.makedirs(path)
File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\os.py", line 220, in makedirs
mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\program files (x86)\\python36-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\wheel'

C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages>
```

"How to overcome this 'permission denied' problem"- where all the folder permissions are changed to read,write and modify! for all users.

Comment: open the command prompt in administrator mode

Comment: Thank you! it worked when opening CMD in ADMINISTRATOR mode.